# how to automatically generate schema for django graphql

Tags: django, graphql

I am working on this project: https://github.com/mirumee/saleor
This project uses graphql and I am wondering how to generate schema in this folder: https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/tree/master/saleor/graphql
Is there a way to automatically generate schema? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [**`graphql_schema`**](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/introspection/#graphql-sdl-representation) management command as

```
python manage.py graphql_schema --schema tutorial.quickstart.schema --out schema.graphql
```

Note that, the **`--out`** file must have the extension ***`.graphql`*** to generate the *GraphQL SDL* representation.

Comment: This will only generate schema.graphql, right? How about all the folders and files in https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/tree/master/saleor/graphql
Are those folders and files generated automatically?

Comment: No, those files are hand written by maintainers.

Comment: Then, what is the purpose to generate schema.graphql?

Comment: You can use it in your `TypeScript`, if you want

Comment: But this is not my question. What is the purpose to generate schema.graphql? Where in the code was schema.graphql used?

Comment: Your question was "how to generate schema" and I addressed that. The "purpose" was not part of the OP

Comment: I know. But if you can answer the purpose, it will be even better. Thanks

Comment: checkout the official [doc](https://graphql.org/learn/introspection/)